# Reopening a question does not clear the custom duplicate list created by gold hammer

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

I noticed a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298688/you-can-only-post-once-every-40-minutes) that was closed as duplicate, but the dupe targets were wrong. Gold hammer edited the list to add another target in addition to the original, but still  both were wrong.

I did find a correct dupe target, so I reopened the question (using my own hammer) and closed as duplicate of the other question I found. To my surprise, the wrong duplicates appeared again!

I had to manually edit the list of duplicates, and now it's fine. Still, reopening should clear this list.

The bug can be seen in the [revisions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/298688/revisions):

> [image]

Comment: Maybe you should not only have used a golden *hammer*, but also golden "nails"?!?!